# How to publish on my own Facebook Page (graph-api) without creating an App on Facebook developer

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-permissions

I have several Facebook pages, to manage them all (publish photo or generally post as the page), I've created a simple script in python which needs the Page ID and the Access Token.
To get the Access Token I need to make a Facebook app.
I'm able to publish on my facebook pages using the access token taken from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/.
The problem is that if I don't set the app status to live, the post on the FB Page are not visible.
If I change the app status to live, I no longer have the permission required to publish, because I need to submit the app for review, but the script that I created doesn't fall in any of the categories listed; i.e. Facebook Web Games, Website, iOS, etc.
So my questions are:

- How do I make visible to the public the posts made by the app,
  leaving the app status as "In Development"?
- Is there a way to publish to a FB Page, without the need to create an
  app on FB?

Comment: 1) You don’t. 2) Yes, the UI :-) An app id is the basis for all stuff you do via the APIs. _“but the script that I created doesn't fall in any of the categories listed”_ - doesn’t matter, check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps on instructions for how to submit this kind of app.

Comment: I'm in the same scenario. How did you do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are personally an admin of the pages, then using your personal user access token, you can request a page access token via the API.  Then use that to do the operation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/#page-access-tokens

```
$ okurl https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/me/accounts?fields=access_token,name --token XXXXXXXXU
{
  "data": [
    {
      "access_token": "XXXX1",
      "name": "Page 1",
      "id": "99999999"
    },
    {
      "access_token": "XXXX2",
      "name": "Page 2",
      "id": "99999999"
    },
    {
      "access_token": "XXXX3",
      "name": "Page 3",
      "id": "99999999"
    },
```

Comment: Can also do this without create an app?

Answer (score 0):

when you turn your app live , the old invisible posts will be public .